# Where in the Win7 registry is the wallpaper slideshow folder?

Tags: desktop-customization

I want to schedule a .bat file to change the location of the wallpaper slideshow folder every evening (so I can use a folder of 'night' images at night).

I can only find the registry location of the *current wallpaper*, but not the location of the slideshow folder. Where is it kept?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the wallpaper location and wallpaper fit in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop.
```

The information about the slideshow is not in the Windows registry. You have to open this path:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\
```

and make sure, that hidden files are visible (you can change that in folder options).

The info is in `slideshow.ini`. There are tags for root slideshow image and slideshows as ImagesRootPIDL which is uuencoded PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE struct which you could use to manipulate the location of the folder. I think working with two seperate `slideshow.ini` files which you exchange seems to be the easier way.

**EDIT**
The basic process is (no way around due to MS internals to set Wallpaper from one Slideshow to another Slideshow

- Copy the backed up slideshow.ini file back into the theme directory
- Stop-process -name explorer
- Sleep 1 sec, and start up explorer only if it hasn't automatically restarted

Comment: That is wonderful, thank you Codebreaker007. I will use your suggestion of using two separate slideshow.ini files. Now I just need to work out how to convert the uuencoded location into regular text!?

Comment: No need to decode the uuencoded. Just do a setup via explorer/control panel for day settings (including pics, slideshow, transistions and so on) - save ini file as day_slideshow.ini, repeat for night settings and you have two configured files. De/Encoding is only necessary if you want to directly write into that file via C++ or similar.

Comment: Wow. That's brilliant! Thank you so much sir!

Comment: Update: I've just tested this and have a problem. When I copy a new slideshow.ini into that folder (overwriting the original), the new version is ignored and images from the original folder continue to be displayed.

Comment: You have to write your batch as in my edit

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that the location does update automatically if you wait long enough.